# What does "government" refer to?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-request

> There is a policy in **the current government** to show itself victimized by suggesting some men who won't pass the Gaurdian Council's filter.

It's the literal translation of a quote by a conservative man about the presidential policy of the current president of Iran for the next round.

I think *the current government* is not a good choice for the current political pary in power because **the government** could be the whole system. Right?

If yes, what is the common phrase to call the president of a country and their cabinet which govern a country at the moment?

If no, what's the term for the whole system. Regime?

Answer (score 1):

It is a common practice around the world to refer to the political party in power as "government". The speaker of the sentence has used the word "government" in order to convey the same meaning that you have thought of. The speaker wants to imply that the "whole system" of governance has broken down under the current regime so as to portray the inefficaciousness of the present political party or president in power.

As far as some specific word he could have said **incumbent president or party**.

Comment: If the political party in power is called "government", then what the whole system in power is called?

Comment: @Ahmad - It's also called the government.  You just have to understand the difference from context.

Comment: +1.  **Government** can refer generally to the entire apparatus or the system, or it can refer specifically to the party in power and its administration, the bureaucrats it installs.  With the adjective *current*, the reference is clearly to the ruling party and its administration.

Answer (score 1):

As a native English speaker, I would say "the ruling party" to refer to the current political party in power.  I would use "the state" to refer to the whole system in power.

Comment: And when do you use government?